# Animating canvas' .stroke() without external libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I know it's been asked quite a lot (I did google it), but how can I animate .stroke() command on canvas? I found some examples, but they all rely on external overpowered (for my purposes) libraries or require use of pre-generated SVG files.
I have this page [here](https://simbiat.ru/main.html) (I know it sucks, but I am learning the curves with it among other things). What I need is to make the lines coming of the bottom "button" to "grow" or have an effect at least similar to what other buttons provide with circle. For circles I used jquery's knob library, but for lines... It feels like this can be done with transformation or something, but I can't put my finger on it. Any advice?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I believe I did explain what I need (actually the subject itself is pretty self-explanatory)... Also I do not believe I asked to "fix" a "broken" site. At the least my site is not broken

Comment: You posted a link to a site that this question is about. If that link goes offline, the question loses all it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, but the easiest (and native) method doesn't require much code. Here is a **[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/nayalavova/2/edit?html,output)** of a `canvas stroke()` animation. The accompanying JavaScript is below. This is a very simple example, but it should give you the right idea.

```
var canvasObj = function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      x = 0,
      y = 0,

      animate = function() {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( 0, 0 );
        ctx.lineTo( x,y );
        ctx.stroke();

        x += 5;
        y += 2.5;

        setTimeout( animate, 200 );
      };


  return {
    'animate': animate
  };

};
```

**Explanation:** The thing that makes this work is the `closure` that is created by the internal function `animate` within the `canvasObj` function. The variables `x` and `y` are available at the parent function level, and can be manipulated by the `animate` function. `animate` is calling itself by using `setTimeout` which creates the animation effect. And that's really it. Hope this helps you get on your way.

Comment: I was thinking in this direction, but something told me that it will be required to calculate each point's precise position for smooth animation... I will try this today and let you know if it does achieve what I require.

Comment: In the end I decided to use setInterval like this

  `var timerId = setInterval(function() {

   context.beginPath(); 

   context.moveTo(x1min, y1min); 

   context.lineTo(x1cur, y1cur); 

   context.lineWidth = "5"; 

   context.strokeStyle = "#87CEEB"; 
   context.lineCap = "round"; 
   context.stroke(); 
   x1cur -= 8.7 
   y1cur += 3 
   if (y1cur == y1max) { 
    clearInterval(timerId); 
   } 
  }, 50);` 

still playing with growth speed, but the idea is understandable, I guess. Marking your post as "answer"